# Check if row exists in an xml

Tags: javascript, xml

I wanna be able to check if my xml, **xmlChecklistItem** already contains a certain row.

my code:

```
var node = xmlTemp.selectSingleNode("//ChecklistItem/Row");
```

where my node.xml is equal to the ff:

```
<Row piID="S000000051" piItemName="Communications - Cable TV"/>
```

and xmlChecklistItem goes like this:

```
<ChecklistItem>
<Row piID="S000000051" piItemName="Communications - Cable TV"/>
</ChecklistItem>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string xPath="//ChecklistItem/Row[@piID='S000000051'];
var node = xmlTemp.selectSingleNode(xPath);

if(node == null){
// the row does not exist
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use xPath for it

`var node = xmlTemp.selectSingleNode("//ChecklistItem/Row[@piID='S000000051']");`

Comment: Might worth pointing out that you are making use of an attribute selector (the brackets and the at sign) `Node[@your-attribute='value']`. More on xPath: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript